# TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to float

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, typeerror

I am trying to create a histogram over time using matplotlib in python.
I have an array of datetime.datetime objects.

```
2016-01-16 11:50:01
2016-01-16 11:48:34
2016-01-16 11:48:28
2016-01-16 11:44:29
```

I have doubled check that they are datetime.datetime.

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Here is my snippet of my code:

```
f1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = f1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.hist(arrayofdates, bins=50, color='lightblue')
```

At line "ax1.hist....", I get this error output

> File "akpsql.py", line 131, in create_histograms
>   ax1.hist(arrayofdates, bins=50, color='lightblue') File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8312, in hist
>   xmin = min(xmin, xi.min()) TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime
>   to float

The thing is, this code works completely fine when I test it on my VM with a small arraysize of around 10.

However, when I try on bigger sample size on a server, there are around 8000+ results.

1. Is there a way to fix this problem?
2. Is there a more optimal way to plot frequency over time (especially when there are huge results?  Like will bin size be an issue?)

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Confirmed that even using the small 10 array dates on this server causes this same problem on exact line (When I replace arrayofdates with the array with the 10 dates)

Confirmed that all entries in the array are all datetime.datetime objects

Confirmed matplotlib is up to date

Comment: You changed two parameters (different system, different sample size); so it would be good to find out, which causes the issue. Will the small array work on the server?

Comment: If you want to ensure all 8000 are `datetime`, you might try printing `set(map(type, arrayofdates))`. Should make it obvious if it's _really_ all the same type.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I printed your command, and confirmed it is datetime.datetime only.  --> set([<type 'datetime.datetime'>])

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried using the small array on server, it still doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Have you added an appropriate (date aware) locator to your plot?

Comment: Is this supposed to be before the histogram command?  I do have locator code afterwards to help create my axis, but that is not causing the error.  and because it works on my VM, that is not the issue @donkopotamus

Comment: @Tony ... are you using identical version of `matplotlib` with identical configs on VM and server?

Comment: The error seems to be produced in `"matplotlib/axes.py", line 8312"`; however the current matplotlib version does not have an `axes.py`. The `hist` function is located in `"axes/_axes.py"` (which has only ~7000 lines). So I doubt you have the latest version installed. You should find out and report back which version you have on the respective systems.

Comment: donkopotamus  You were right, the VM and server versions were different.   @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The latest version was not installed and that caused the problem.    Thank you both